How do you prove transitivity of equality?
There are only two axioms of equality in SQML, reflexivity (RX), and substitution (II).  Obviously you can prove transitivity of equality, but how does the proof go?
Reflexivity (RX)

∀x[x = x]

Substitution (II)

(A = B ∧ φ(A)) → φ(B)


I'm a bit confused by the wording of the question: it's obvious to you that you can prove transitivity, but you don't have a proof?

@naim, it's obvious because others have developed SQML to have transitivity and symmetry of equality as theorems.  I was wondering how you prove it in their system, but I figured it out.

Given A = B and B = C, use substitution with A := B, B := C, φ(x) := (A = x). This is similar to the way you prove transitivity of Martin-Löf's identity type.

Let φ(x) be (A=x & x=C).  Then
φ(B) is (A=B & B=C), which is the hypothesis. Thus, φ(B) is true.  Therefore, B=C & φ(B).  Now by substitution φ(C).  Therefore, (A=C & C=C).  Thus, A=C.
Hence, if A=B & B=C then A=C, which is transitivity of equality.

You can drop the x = C part, see my answer.
